# How to Initialize the List with the same element in flutter dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list in dart I want to initialize the list with `n` number of the same element.
example:- initialize the integer list with element `5` 4 times.
          `List<int> temp = [5,5,5,5];`
what are different ways to initialize the list in dart flutter?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is [`List.filled`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/List/List.filled.html):

`List.filled(int length, E fill, { bool growable: false })`.

The params would be:

- length - the number of elements in the list
- E fill - what element should be contained in the list
- growable - if you want to have a dynamic length;

So you could have:

`List<int> zeros = List.filled(10, 0)`

This would create a list with ten zeros in it.

One think you need to pay attention is if you're using objects to initialise the list for example:

```
SomeObject a = SomeObject();
List<SomeObject> objects = List.filled(10, a);
```

The list created above will have the same instance of object a on all positions.

---

If you want to have new objects on each position you could use [`List.generate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/List/List.generate.html):

`List.generate(int length, E generator(int index), {bool growable:true})`

Something like:

`List<SomeObject> objects = List<SomeObject>.generate(10, (index) => SomeObject(index)`;

OR:

```
List<SomeObject> objects = List<SomeObject>.generate(10, (index) { 
      SomeOjbect obj = SomeObject(index)
      obj.id= index;
      return obj;
});
```

This will create a new instance for each position in list. The way you initialise the object is up to you.

Comment: that's the problem I want to initialise the object? is there any way to create same object multiple times?

Comment: while generating how to refer to this object which is being generated? will `this` keyword works?

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this

```
List<int>.generate(4, (int index) => 5);
```

For more, [read this](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/List/List.generate.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified version of the accepted answer. You can use a **list literal**, a **filled list**, or a **generated list**:

```dart
final literal = [5, 5, 5, 5];
final filled = List.filled(4, 5);
final generated = List.generate(4, (index) => 5);

print(literal);   // [5, 5, 5, 5]
print(filled);    // [5, 5, 5, 5]
print(generated); // [5, 5, 5, 5]
```

When you just want to fill the list with the same values, `List.filled` is good. Unless you literally want `[5, 5, 5, 5]`. In that case, just use the list literal. It's easy to read and understand.